# WPF DragLeave EventTrigger not always working

Tags: c#, wpf, eventtrigger

I'm having some issues with a user control that I've put together, which is sort of directional keys that a user can drop an object on, which then puts the new object in the direction of the drop. I've hooked up the highlighting using EventTriggers and it seems to be working fine around 95% of the time - eg. user drags something over the control, the appropriate control highlights. The user drags the item off or drops it on the highlighted control and the control gets unhighlighted. The issue is that sometimes, especially when quickly moving a dragged object around multiple of the directional controls, some of the controls fail to lose the highlight. I am not doing anything in the code-behind at all and the only thing that drives it is this xaml.

Any ideas?

**CrossDropControl.xaml User Control - no code behind**

```
<UserControl x:Class="EventTriggersDemo.CrossDropControl"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:EventTriggersDemo"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="DirectionalBorderStyle"
               TargetType="Border">
            <Setter Property="Height" Value="28" />
            <Setter Property="Width" Value="28" />
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FF323232" />
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Black" />
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1" />
            <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="True" />
            <Setter Property="AllowDrop" Value="True" />
            <Style.Triggers>
                <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="DragEnter">
                    <BeginStoryboard x:Name="DragEnterStoryboard">
                        <Storyboard>
                            <ColorAnimation Duration="0:0:0.1" 
                                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background.Color"
                                            To="LightBlue" />
                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>
                </EventTrigger>
                <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="DragLeave">
                    <StopStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="DragEnterStoryboard" />
                </EventTrigger>
                <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Drop">
                    <StopStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="DragEnterStoryboard" />
                </EventTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>

        <Style x:Key="DirectionalShapeStyle"
               TargetType="Shape">
            <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="True" />
            <Setter Property="Fill" Value="Gray" />
        </Style>

    </UserControl.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <Border Name="dropPopupControl"
                Width="98"
                Height="98">
            <Grid>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition />
                    <RowDefinition />
                    <RowDefinition />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition />
                    <ColumnDefinition />
                    <ColumnDefinition />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                <Path x:Name="CompassBodyIcon"
                      Grid.RowSpan="3"
                      Grid.ColumnSpan="3"
                      Width="98"
                      Height="98"
                      Data="F1 M 0,32.0045L 21.0029,32.0045L 32.0045,21.0029L 32.0045,7.62939e-006L 66.0092,7.62939e-006L 66.0092,21.0029L 77.0107,32.0045L 98.0137,32.0045L 98.0137,66.0092L 77.0107,66.0092L 66.0092,77.0107L 66.0092,98.0137L 32.0045,98.0137L 32.0045,77.0107L 21.0029,66.0092L 0,66.0092L 0,32.0045 Z "
                      Fill="Gray"
                      SnapsToDevicePixels="True"
                      Stretch="Fill"
                      Stroke="Black" />
                <Border x:Name="PART_LeftIndicator"
                        Grid.Row="1"
                        Grid.Column="0"
                        Margin="2,0,0,0"
                        Style="{StaticResource DirectionalBorderStyle}">
                    <Path x:Name="LeftPlacementIndicator"
                          Data="F1 M 7.00043,13.0018L 22.0025,22.0031L 22.0025,4.00056L 7.00043,13.0018 Z "
                          Style="{StaticResource DirectionalShapeStyle}" />
                </Border>
                <Border x:Name="PART_RightIndicator"
                        Grid.Row="1"
                        Grid.Column="2"
                        Margin="0,0,2,0"
                        Style="{StaticResource DirectionalBorderStyle}">
                    <Path x:Name="RightHighlightVisual"
                          Data="F1 M 19.0025,13.0018L 4.00042,4.00056L 4.00042,22.0031L 19.0025,13.0018 Z "
                          Style="{StaticResource DirectionalShapeStyle}" />

                </Border>
                <Border x:Name="PART_BottomIndicator"
                        Grid.Row="2"
                        Grid.Column="1"
                        Margin="0,0,0,2"
                        Style="{StaticResource DirectionalBorderStyle}">
                    <Path x:Name="BottomPlacementIndicator"
                          Data="F1 M 12.9824,19.002L 21.9837,3.99995L 3.98116,3.99995L 12.9824,19.002 Z "
                          Style="{StaticResource DirectionalShapeStyle}" />
                </Border>
                <Border x:Name="PART_TopIndicator"
                        Grid.Column="1"
                        Margin="0,2,0,0"
                        Style="{StaticResource DirectionalBorderStyle}">
                    <Path x:Name="TopPlacementIndicator"
                          Data="F1 M 13.0022,7.021L 4.0009,22.0231L 22.0034,22.0231L 13.0022,7.021 Z "
                          Style="{StaticResource DirectionalShapeStyle}" />
                </Border>
                <Border x:Name="PART_CenterIndicator"
                        Grid.Row="1"
                        Grid.Column="1"
                        Margin="2"
                        Style="{StaticResource DirectionalBorderStyle}">
                    <Ellipse Margin="4"
                             Style="{StaticResource DirectionalShapeStyle}" />
                </Border>
            </Grid>
        </Border>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
    <Window x:Class="EventTriggersDemo.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:EventTriggersDemo"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" 
        Height="350" 
        Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition />
            <ColumnDefinition />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <ListBox x:Name="dragListBox" PreviewMouseMove="UIElement_OnPreviewMouseMove">
            <ListBox.Items>
                <ListBoxItem>Item 1</ListBoxItem>
                <ListBoxItem>Item 2</ListBoxItem>
                <ListBoxItem>Item 3</ListBoxItem>
            </ListBox.Items>
        </ListBox>

        <local:CrossDropControl Grid.Column="1" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

**// MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```
    using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Input;

namespace EventTriggersDemo
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void UIElement_OnPreviewMouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            // Get some mock drag data
            var dragData = new DataObject("Test Data");
            DragDrop.DoDragDrop(dragListBox, dragData, DragDropEffects.Move);
        }
    }
}
```

What I noticed while preparing this example is that removing the *PlacementIndicator paths, which are wrapped by Border controls seems to either remove this issue completely or minimize it to an extent which results in me not being able to reproduce it. I do not see how that would affect this behavior however...

Any ideas at all?

Comment: you might want to share a full, repeatable code/project for this, it's hard to tell just by looking at this.

Comment: Good idea! I've expanded the sample code to include everything that is needed. MainWindow.xaml and MainWindow.xaml.cs, which uses the CrossDropControl.xaml